# Write requests are only supported on contained entities, Microsoft Graph API when trying to PATCH/POST to assign AD App role to user

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to assign app-specific roles to a user in our AD group using Microsoft Graph.

The link I'm sending the request to:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{oID of the user I want to assign the role to}/appRoleAssignments/{Object ID of the AD enterprise app}`

Inside the request:

`{"id": "ID of the role I'm trying to assign to the user"}`

The error:

`"code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Write requests are only supported on contained entities",`

The documentation doesn't define parameters in the example well and I've tried various possibilities but this is the only meaningful result I've gotten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't current supported by Microsoft Graph. To *create* app role assignments, you'll need to use Azure AD Graph:

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user-object-id}/appRoleAssignments

{
    "principalId": "{user-object-id}",
    "resourceId": "{service-principal-object-id}",
    "id": "{app-role-id}"
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to assign existing users to existing roles. But I'm thinking your wording is just to point out that the process of doing that is to 'create' app role assignments. 

If that's not possible yet, I don't want to deal with getting 2 graph tokens in my app and do operations via 2 different api's as I have other main graph features in the app. 

I will bypass it by assigning groups to roles and then just adding/removing people from those groups via Graph. 

Thanks for clearing all of this up!

Comment: Yes, if you have the licenses to assign groups to apps, that's probably a better approach anyway.

Comment: Any hints on getting the Azure AD JWT would be appreciated. I can get the above POST working on Azure AD Graph Explorer, but failing to achieve the same with code.

Comment: @JariTurkia Your best bet is to ask a new question (and tag it [azure-active-directory] and [microsoft-graph]). Dont' forget to include what you've tried so far, and what issues you've faced.