# Create a new role assignment for an enterprise application using Graph beta version

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create role assignments for an enterprise application using Graph api beta version .

I am following Microsoft document to do the same

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Error:

This is the error I am getting while checking :

> Write requests are only supported on contained entities

I tried the same using the Azure AD Graph also(graph.windows.net) and I am able to achieve the following.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Write requests are only supported on contained entities",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "f8b80735-c516-4a65-9f42-2b3088f2951a",
      "date": "2019-07-30T09:23:13"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your request sample?

Comment: POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignments

Comment: Actually I want to know your request body.

Comment: JSON body: {
   "creationTimestamp": "2019-05-24T06:55:12.0912852Z",
            "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "principalDisplayName": "",
            "principalId": "",
            "principalType": "",
            "resourceDisplayName": "",
            "resourceId": ""
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue via Microsoft Graph API, not sure what causes the issue. **Also**, it is a `Beta` version, I don't recommend you to use it in your production environment.

The Azure AD Graph API works for me, you could refer to the request sample as below.

**Note**: The `id` is the role id which was declared by the target resource application resourceId in its `appRoles` property. My sample application does not declare any permissions, so I specify a default id (zero GUID `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`).

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/servicePrincipals/<objetc id of the service principal>/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6 

{
    "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "principalId":"<object id of the user/group/service principal being granted the access>",
    "resourceId":"<objetc id of the service principal which the assignment was made>"

}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok..Thanks..This works for me also....But I wanted to know if I can do with graph.microsoft.com

Comment: @treasa I am not sure what causes the issue. As I mentioned, it is a `Beta` version, if you want to create the assignment in your production environment, it is better to use the Azure AD Graph API.

Comment: @treasa Maybe it is not supported by Microsoft Graph currently, find a similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764985/write-requests-are-only-supported-on-contained-entities-microsoft-graph-api-whe), the guy works in Azure AD team points that.